# Supplemental Document support in SDK and Swagger definition

Tags: docusignapi

Are supplemental documents supported as part of the currently available SDKs?  I can't seem to find reference to the properties includeInDownload, display, and signerMustAcknowledge on the Document object ([src/main/csharp/DocuSign/eSign/Model/Document.cs](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-csharp-client/blob/master/sdk/src/main/csharp/DocuSign/eSign/Model/Document.cs))

Is the DocuSign API swagger definition made publicly available?  The only definition I can find is available here ([DocuSign REST API Swagger JSON](https://gist.github.com/mikebz/bc801337c2d1f6faa8b5/ef5e8f5704a337b9acef34b4c48648a187e1ebb6)) and it's dated July 8th 2015.  When reading through the definition includeInDownload, display, and signerMustAcknowledge aren't included on the Document object (which makes sense seeing I believe this is a new feature that became available around December 2016 according to DocuSign's Solution Architect, Global Partner Solutions).

Answer (score 0):

Those attributes are documented and definitely part of the DocuSign REST API (see envelopeDocument under Definitions [here](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeDocuments/list/)).

```
display (string) : modal, download, inline
includeInDownload (string) : When set to true, the document is included in the combined document download. The default value is true.
signerMustAcknowledge (string) : no_interaction, view, accept, view_accept
```

However, they don't seem to have been included as part of the newly released C# SDK as of today (see the DocuSign NuGet package 2.1.0 [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DocuSign.eSign.dll/))

Answer (score 0):

The [C# SDK](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-csharp-client) has been updated and now supports supplemental documents.